# pre-authenticate user in aspx application

Tags: asp.net, node.js, formsauthentication

We have 2 application, one is in Nodejs and the other in aspx. 
The login page is in Nodejs. What I need is to create a session and authenticate my user in aspx application from the login page for later navigation in the aspx app.

 Being a noob in web development, I have no clue where to start or what to search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dalorzo that's not entirely true, it's just not necessarily easy or necessary to do so.  If your apps are in the same domain and you're doing session storage in a place that's accessible to both, then it's possible. It's also possible if you do it through some version of OAuth between the apps.  To Harmo, why do you need to do it this way? why not login through the aspx app if you're doing most nav there?

Comment: @Paul but if you say it is possible show us how. Wouldn't be easier than changing the original question :)?

Comment: @Dalorzo because as I said it's not easy and so I don't want to take the time/effort to do it if it's not really necessary to solve his problem.

Comment: @Paul questions are not meant to be easy :)

Comment: @Dalorzo Your linked question is absolutely unrelated to this. He's not talking about accessing cookies on the client side, he's using NodeJS together with ASP.NET, NodeJS may be JavaScript but runs on the server.

Comment: @Aidiakapi I know that but to avoid a misunderstanding I deleted it.

Comment: How are you authenticating a user in NodeJS? Do you control this process, or don't you have access to the NodeJS code. Why are you using NodeJS in corporation with ASP.NET, is it absolutely necessary? Can both NodeJS and ASP.NET access the database with the security information required to authenticate a user?

Comment: Hope this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329187/access-asp-net-authentication-ticket-on-client-via-javascript

Comment: @Dalorzo I'll be reminding you again of linking a question about accessing the session cookie on the client side. He's not trying to access it on the client side, he's trying to access it on the server side in a different environment.

Comment: @Paul The authentication need to be made on node.js cause it's the main application that will manage user and config. The aspx app is an utility to the first one.

Comment: @Aidiakapi I have access to NodeJS code. The asp app is a utility aleready developped that need to use the user list of the first one. Both app use Microsoft sql server but they are on different bd. Yes they can access the database. I'll discuss with teamate tomorow about shared session.

Comment: @Dalorzo Sure, but not all questions are meant to be answered, either. Sometimes it's far more useful to provide a solution to the problem than a simple answer to a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there's several ways I can think of to do this, depending on your current intent for both applications and reasons for doing what you're doing.  I'll try and list each here with some pro's and cons.  I'll say again that none are what I'd consider easy for a new web developer; are there others on your team that have experience in one or both technologies?

1) Probably the simplest option, if you can do it is to have the Node.js process be the gateway. The ASP.NET application never needs to authenticate the users at all, the Node.js app acts as a full-on reverse proxy to the ASP.NET app.  This works well if you can support it, and  you can secure it by having the Node.js application login to the ASP.Net app (via whatever method you want; basic auth, forms login, whatever).  If you need the ASP.Net app to be aware of what user is in the current context, then you can push whatever info you need into the request headers to do so (e.g. if they share the same database, you coudl put in the Id of the user that the node app has authenticated).  If you wanted the ASP.NET app to be accessible on its own as well as via the node app, then the node app becomes one of many users and the asp.net app needs a HTTP Module to normalize whether the user info is coming from Session or from the Http headers.  The easiest way to do this is to have the Http Module check that the current user is of a given role (e.g. NodeApp) and is logged in, and then it either copies the user information from the HttpContext into a new Session variable (that the rest of the app uses), or else looks up the proxied user in the DB and does the same.  Basically, the rest of the app will never trust the HttpContext's current user for making decisions at that point.

Pro's:  reasonably simple architecture, does not depend on what domain each app is on.  Both apps need access to the user DB for it to work well.

Con's:  If for some reason the apps can't have access to the same user db it isn't as good.  There's some overhead for doing the proxy (not much, but still there). There's a bit of brain bending around whether you're talking about the 'real' user or the 'node' user that you have to keep straight.

2) OAuth (or alternatively OpenID) is the most standards-compliant option.  In this case, you'd setup the Node.js app as an OAuth provider and have the ASP.NET app be an OAuth consumer.  The user can then use their Node username and password to login, and have the Node app pass an auth token to the ASP.NET app via existing authentication modules.

Pro's:  Less code to write on the ASP.NET side than the above example, standards compliant. you could switch out (or add) OAuth providers if you wanted to later

Con's:  A bit more indirection for the user (redirects between the apps).  This can probably be minimized, but you'll need to be very familiar with the OAuth protocols.

3) Session sharing (considered session hijacking if someone else is doing it to you. . . ).  If you're on the same domain, then the Node.js app can simply write out the ASP.NET session and auth cookies like ASP.NET would.  I say 'simply', but there's a lot of details of the ASP.NET machinery that you'll need to understand to do it right. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443 .  The main bits are that you'd need to put your ASP.NET Session Store in a database, and then have Node.js manage the addition and removal of elements from there so that when ASP.NET goes looking at the session & auth cookies on a given request, it can find them in the place it expects to find them and then the ASP.NET process would find them there and act accordingly.

Pro's:  Uses the ASP.NEt machinery that's already in place to some degree
Con's:  Probably pretty fragile, all things considered. Your node.js app would need access to the machineKey that the ASP.NEt app is going to use to decrypt the session contents. You'll need to make sure you're using the same encryption algorithm and both apps would be coupled to the same session store.

4) Roll your own membership provider in ASP.NET to issue a Forms Auth ticket to the Node app. This is somewhat similar to a blend of 1 and 3.  In this option, the Node app, after authenticating the user, would send another request to a Login endpoint on the ASP.Net server, providing it credentials identifying itself however you want (e.g. a shared key that's been encrypted in some way).  It could also provide any user details you want.  You could then manually call the Forms Authentication api in your ASP.NET code to create a ticket for the end user (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) i.e. no calculating it yourself; session store can be anywhere. The response to the Node.js app will include the ticket data in the auth cookie and so your Node.js app can pipe that data back to your user, so that the next time they make a request to the ASP.nEt app, they'll have a valid auth cookie generated by asp.net.

Pro's:  More flexible than #3 and less user mungery than #1 from the ASP.NET perspective.
Con's:  Still requires both apps on the same domain, still requires a lot of integration between the two.  If you screw up your Membership provider you could accidentally create a hole in your security.

Overall, I think the OAuth solution is the best one, but those are all the methods I can think of to do it.

Comment: Thank you for now, I'll study the different possibilities and come back with feedback

Comment: solution 4 because other part of the application use this technique. Thank you again